# Reverse poco c# bulk insert Entity Framework "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bulkinsert

Weird situation: I'm getting a bulkinsert failure using the code below. The weird thing is it works if I set the `DbContext` name to a specific name, but fails if I change it.

With nothing else different, if I edit the reverse poco tt file, and change the `DbContext` name to a specific name and save it (recreating the Entity Framework files), it works. If I do the same thing but change it in any way, it will fail when the code hits the `bulkinsert()` line.

It makes absolutely no sense to me. I can't set it to the working one because that working one is already being used in the same project (I tested this in a new project just trying to figure out the problem.)

```
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    db.BulkInsert(recordsToInsert);
    db.SaveChanges();
    transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

Any ideas? I know it's not something to do with the table or the fields, because it works with one `dbcontextname` and not any other.

Edit: also, the exception stack trace shows that it's failing here:

```
at EntityFramework.BulkInsert.ProviderFactory.Get(DbContext context)
```

Comment: Can you check your dbcontext name exist in your config file?

Comment: The dbcontext name does exist. In the same method, I'm writing to the same dbcontext only without bulkinsert.  I'm inserting to another table entirely.

Comment: the name of the class which is getting derived from dbcontext is by convention same as the name of the connection string

Comment: Not sure if you've used the reverse poco extension but these things are set in the tt file.  Also, the one that is working is using a different connection string name than the dbcontext as well.  But this is an interesting thought.

Comment: OMG!  Fakhar you were right.  The reason it was working for the other instance is because I had another connection string name in the app config using that name.  When I tried it in the application making the dbcontext name the same as the connection string name, it worked!  Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Fakhar Ahmad Rasul posted the solution in the comments.  It turns out that the dbcontext name has to be the same as the connection string name.  Thanks Fakhar!  I wish I could award you points or something.